# Evaluate the integral with and without Green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the line integral $\oint_C y^2dx + xdy$ when $C$ has the vector equation $\alpha(t)=(2\cos^3t)i+(2\sin^3t)j$, $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

My attempt

BY USING GREEN's THEOREM,

i.e., $P=y^2$, $Q=x$

we get $\iint_c 1-2y dxdy$

Now putting $x=r\cos^3t$ and $y=r\sin^3t$

we get $dxdy=Jdrdt$, where $J=3r \sin^2t \cos^2t$

hence $dxdy=3r \sin^2t \cos^2t drdt$

Hence the required integral is,

$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 (1-2r \sin^3t)(3r \sin^2t \cos^2t)drdt$

which is equal to $\pi /4$

But the answer given in APOSTOL's is $3 \pi /2$

NOW BY NORMAL METHOD

put $x=2 \cos^3t$ and $y=2 \sin^3t$

$dx=-6 \cos^2t \sin t dt$ and $dy=6 \sin^2t cost dt$,

Hence the integral becomes $-24 \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^7t \cos^2t dt + 12 \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos^4t \sin^2t dt$ which is equal to ZERO.

WHAT MISTAKE AM I DOING AND THE CORRECT ANSWER IS $3 \pi /2$  ?

Comment: I think that the parametrization isnt suited for the greens theorem, that of course isnt the reason for the wrong solution

Comment: You wrote out both the $dr dt$ integral and the $dt$ integral correctly, you just evaluated them incorrectly. Both are equal to $3 \pi/2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Your second method**

Use [$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^n x\ dx=\dfrac{2\pi}{2^{2k}}{2k\choose k}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2925429/108128)
for even $n=2k$ and for odd $n$ it is zero, then
$$-24 \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^7t \cos^2t dt + 12 \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos^4t \sin^2t dt$$
$$-24\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^7t (1-\sin^2t) dt + 12 \int_0^{2 \pi} (1-\sin^2t)^2\sin^2t dt$$
$$-24\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^7t\ dt + 24\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^9t\ dt + 12\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^2t\ dt -24 \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^4t\ dt + 12\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^6t\ dt $$
$$0+0+12\dfrac{2\pi}{2^{2}}{2\choose 1} -24\dfrac{2\pi}{2^{4}}{4\choose 2} + 12\dfrac{2\pi}{2^{6}}{6\choose 3}=\color{blue}{\dfrac{3\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: Based on a representative sample of one user, 0% of the users are going to notice that the first formula is a link.

Comment: @Maxim i didnt notice :)